# DataTable.Compute fails when evaluating a decimal expression

Tags: c#, datatables, evaluation

I am using the Compute method of the DataTable class to evaluate and expression.
When the value is a whole number the evaluation works, when the expression is a decimal value, the evaluation fails. I get a "System.FormatException" exception.

Here is the sample code:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var passingResult = dt.Compute("CONVERT('100', 'System.Decimal') > 3", null);   //works
var failingResult = dt.Compute("CONVERT('100.1', 'System.Decimal') > 3", null); //fails
```

Comment: Both work fine if I run the code

Comment: Both must  works fine....!!

Comment: For some reason when I have the single quotes it fails on my side. I removed the quotes around the number and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoring to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cabd21yw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Real literals without scientific notation, but with a decimal point, are treated as System.Decimal. If the number exceeds the maximum or minimum values supported by System.Decimal, then it is parsed as a System.Double. For example:
>
> 142526.144524 will be converted to a Decimal.
>
> 345262.78036719560925667 will be treated as a Double.

So use just simply `dt.Compute("100.1 > 3", null)` and it will be okay.

Comment: Thanks @taffer. Will this not cause issues when the culture changes (say when moving from one environmet to another)?

Comment: No, because these are number literals. The problem arises only when you use conversion from string.

Answer (score 3):

Initially I weren't able to reproduce your problem, but then with this code

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("af-ZA");
var dt = new DataTable();
var passingResult = dt.Compute("CONVERT('100', 'System.Decimal') > 3", null);   //works
var failingResult = dt.Compute("CONVERT('100.1', 'System.Decimal') > 3", null); //fails
```

I got the same formatting error, so it is a problem of culture info applied to your code. I could resolve it with this code

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var dt = new DataTable();
passingResult = dt.Compute("CONVERT('100', 'System.Decimal') > 3", null);   //works
failingResult = dt.Compute("CONVERT('100.1', 'System.Decimal') > 3", null); //fails
```

Not sure if this is the best way to solve it, because it could be problematic for the code that follows the usage of your table and I am pretty sure that you need to reset your CultureInfo after this change back to your original one.

Let's see if someone else has a better way to solve it.

Comment: Thanks @Steve. This is exactly what was causing the issue. It was using the culture of the current thread. It turns out that here in South Africa the Decimal seperator is a comma instead of a period.